# HTML, how to get always +1 sum

Tags: javascript, html, sum, counter, addition

I'm doing a point counter in general and I have no idea how to do it anymore, so I would like to add +1 to the sum on the "=" button and add it only once if someone could help me, I would be grateful

Code: https://pastebin.com/C26VFyev

```js
var result = 0;

function suma() {
  var cal1 = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["cal1"].value);
  var cal2 = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["cal2"].value);
  var sum = (cal1 + cal2 + 1);
  
  document.forms["form1"]["sum"].value = sum
  result = sum;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form1">
    Cal 1:
    <input value="0" name="cal1" size="5"><br> Cal2:
    <input value="0" name="cal2" size="5"><br>

    <input type="button" value="Oblicz" name="add" onClick="suma();"><br> Suma:
    <input type="text" name="sum" size="6"><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable for what you add to the sum. Initialize it to `1` for the first time, than change it to `0` for future uses.

```js
var result = 0;
var addition = 1;

function suma() {
  var cal1 = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["cal1"].value);
  var cal2 = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["cal2"].value);
  var sum = (cal1 + cal2 + addition);
  if (addition == 1) {
    addition = 0;
  }
  
  document.forms["form1"]["sum"].value = sum
  result = sum;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form1">
    Cal 1:
    <input value="0" name="cal1" size="5"><br> Cal2:
    <input value="0" name="cal2" size="5"><br>

    <input type="button" value="Oblicz" name="add" onClick="suma();"><br> Suma:
    <input type="text" name="sum" size="6"><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```